# Amazon S3 API OAuth-style access to 3-rd party buckets

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oauth, impersonation

I'm a newbie in AWS infrastructure, and I can't figure out how to build auth process which I want.

I want to have something similar to what other cloud storages, like Box, Dropbox, Onedrive have:

1. developer registeres OAuth app with a set of permissions
2. client with one click can give a consent for this app to have listed permissions on his own account and it's content, eternally, until consent is deliberately withdrawn

Now, as far as I understand, client should go to console and create a user, create a role for him, then send this user's id and key to my app, which is not that convinient. I'm looking for a most easy and simple way to do that.

I've tested "Login with Amazon" + "Amazon Cognito", but it turned out as a completely opposite mechanism: client should set up Login, link it to Cognito, to provide me one click access.

So, is it even possible? Which is the best way to implement such auth process?

Comment: Trying to  understand what you are asking... You have written an app that I can use to access my S3 buckets, and you're trying to figure out how I would give your app access to my S3 buckets?  Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: You have S3 with your objects, and I have an app that works with **your** data in **your** account. You want to use my app, and to grant access for my app to your data you just click "I agree" -- like with other services or even social networks. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do what you're trying to do, and I would suggest that there's a conceptual problem with comparing Amazon S3 to Dropbox, Box, or Onedrive -- it's not the same kind of service.

S3 is a service that you could use to *build* a service like those others (among other purposes, of course).

> Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3), provides developers and IT teams with secure, durable, highly-scalable cloud storage.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Note the target audience -- "developers and IT teams" -- not end-users.

Contrast that with Amazon Cloud Drive, another service from Amazon -- but not part of AWS.

> The Amazon Cloud Drive API and SDKs for Android and iOS enable your users to access the photos, videos, and documents that they have saved in the Amazon Cloud Drive, and provides you the ability to interact with millions of Amazon customers. Access to the free Amazon Cloud Drive API and SDKs for Android and iOS enable you to place your own creative spin on how users upload, view, edit, download, and organize their digital content using your app.
>
> https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/

The only way for your app to access your app's user's bucket would be for the user to configure and provide your app with a key and secret, or to configure their bucket policy to allow the operation by your app's credentials, or to create an IAM role and allow your app to assume it on their behalf, or something similar within the authentication and authorization mechanisms in AWS... none of which sound like a good idea.

There's no OAuth mechanism for allowing access to resources in an AWS account.

Comment: I was thinking: is it possible to do smth in IAM, like create user with s3 permissions, using "Login with Amazon" token? Smth similar maybe?